# Refresh session after an update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-variables, session-state

I want session get new value after an update, but this always get old value until I re-login...

I have small screenshot called VIP for Vip member :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVhAZ.png

When I click active Vip, value changes but on View don't have an image.

My view:

```
@if (session.IsVip == false)
{
    <p>Xin Chào @session.UserName!</p>
    <span>@Html.ActionLink("Đăng xuất", "Logout", "User")</span>
}
else
{
    <p>Xin Chào @session.UserName!</p> <img src="~/Assets/Client/img/Vip.png" />
    <span>@Html.ActionLink("Đăng xuất", "Logout", "User")</span>
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Load(string id,khachhang c)
{
    var session = Session[CommonConstants.USER_SESSION] as UserLogin;
    var mm = new MuaVipModel();
    mm.setupvip(session.UserID);
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Load","MuaVip",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Thanh toán thành công, bạn có thể kích hoạt VIP!</h4>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Kích hoạt vip" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[setupVip] 
    @MaKhachHang nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE khachhang 
    SET IsVip = 1 
    WHERE MaKhachHang = @MaKhachHang
END
```

Login:

```
var dao = new UserDao();
var result = dao.Login(model.Username, Encryptor.MD5Hash(model.Password), false);
if (result == 1)
{
    var user = dao.GetById(model.Username);
    var userSession = new UserLogin();
    userSession.UserName = user.Username;
    userSession.UserID = user.MaKhachHang;
    userSession.GroupID = user.MaNhomNguoiDung;
    userSession.IsVip = (bool)user.IsVip;
    var listCredentials = dao.GetListCredential(model.Username);
    Session.Add(CommonConstants.SESSION_CREDENTIALS, listCredentials);
    Session.Add(CommonConstants.USER_SESSION, userSession);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: No where in the code you have shown are you updating anything in `Session`. Its not clear what your asking, or what you expect this code to do.

Comment: see my edit , this is my procedure

Comment: What does that have to do with `Session`!

Comment: i have added login :(

Comment: Will you stop adding snippets (they are not applicable to your code) and learn how to properly format your code. Again, no where in your code are you ever modifying the value in session in your `Load()` method. And you need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials - in particular the section on [Security, Authentication and Authorization](https://www.asp.net/mvc) and learn the fundamental basics.

Comment: Ok, sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want add or update session value anytime then you can write like this:

```
Session["UserName"]="XYZ";  // Session UserName will have value XYZ
```

in your other method if want update this.

```
Session["UserName"]="ABC"; // Session UserName new value ABC
```